# 1548132==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I ran the autograder on my program and got this error but when I run the exact same test case manually it seems to work fine. I am unsure why I get the error only when I use the autograder. I am new to C and I do not understand why the memory leak occurs because I have freed up all the variables that I used malloc on. It shows me what lines specifically cause the error but I do not know how to fix it without "ruining" my code/output.

[image: The error message]

The source code:

```
struct Node* head; //global variable

void Insert(int x){
    struct Node* temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node* ptr = head;
    
    //check if already present
    while(ptr != NULL){
        if(ptr->data == x){return;}
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    
    //check if head is greater
    if(head == NULL || head->data > x){
        temp->data = x;
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;  
    }else{
        ptr = head;
        while(ptr->next != NULL && ptr->next->data < x){
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        
        temp->data = x;
        temp->next = ptr->next;
        ptr->next = temp;
    }
   
}
void Delete(int x){
    struct Node* temp = head;
    struct Node* prev;
    
    //if head has key
    if(temp != NULL && temp->data == x){
        head = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        return;
    }
    
    //find key
    while(temp != NULL && temp->data != x){
        prev=temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    
    //if key isnt present
    if(temp == NULL){return;}
    
    //unlink
    prev->next = temp->next;
    
    free(temp);
}
void Print(){
    struct Node* temp = head;
    int c = 0;
    while(temp != NULL){
        c++;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("%d :", c);
    
    temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL){
        printf(" %d", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(){
    int x;
    char c;
    head = NULL; //empty list
    
    scanf(" %c%d",&c,&x);
    if(c == 'i'){
        Insert(x);
    }else if(c == 'd'){
        Delete(x);  
    }
    Print();
    while(scanf(" %c%d",&c,&x)!=EOF){
        if(c == 'i'){
            Insert(x);
        }else if(c == 'd'){
            Delete(x);
        } 
        Print();
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You will leak the temp variable when ptr->data equals x inside the Insert function. You just return without freeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
void Insert(int x){
    struct Node* temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node* ptr = head;
    
    //check if already present
    while(ptr != NULL){
        if(ptr->data == x){return;}  <--- If this return is executed, temp is not freed
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
```

To fix it just move the `malloc` so it's after the loop.

```
void Insert(int x){
    struct Node* ptr = head;
    
    //check if already present
    while(ptr != NULL){
        if(ptr->data == x){return;}
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    struct Node* temp = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

BTW:

1. Having `head` as a global variable is a bad idea
2. Don't cast the value returned by `malloc`

Comment: You don't know the context of the head variable so you don't if it's a bad idea or not. You should remove that remark.

Comment: @Fredrik no, no, no.... `head` as a global variable is bad in any context

Comment: @4386472 good luck trying to write interrupt code without global variables. Or any embedded code for that matter. People shout the global variable stigma just because they read somewhere it was bad.

Comment: @Fredrik There are cases where global variables are needed but here it's absolutely wrong

Comment: I challenge you, consider the code given by OP, point out where the global variabel in this case causes problems.

Comment: @Fredrik By limiting the use of all functions to a single linked list.

Comment: there is only one list so no problem there.

Comment: @Fredrik That's not an excuse for not writing good code.

Comment: but if the code given is the complete program, then it's not bad code regarding the global variable. My only point with this is, don't push your idea of good or bad code when it has nothing to do with OP's question.

Comment: @Fredrik Good habbits are important but... go ahead and write your programs using globals. Here you can even make `x` a global and still make it work. Have fun with your globals until you have a lot of code which can't be reused, is impossible to maintain, etc... good luck.

Comment: @4386427 Thank you so much!! Can I ask why this works as opposed to what I had?

Comment: @thegrinch If this line `if(ptr->data == x){return;}` resulted in a return, your code leaked the memory assigned to `temp`. Another way to solve your problem would be: `if(ptr->data == x){free(temp); return;}`

Comment: @4386427 Okay that makes a lot of sense, thank you.